# Detect Language of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

Somebody told me about a class for language recognition in Cocoa. 
Does anybody know which one it is?

This is **not** working:

```
NSSpellChecker *spellChecker = [NSSpellChecker sharedSpellChecker];
[spellChecker setAutomaticallyIdentifiesLanguages:YES];
NSString *spellCheckText = @"Guten Tag Herr Mustermann. Dies ist ein deutscher Text. Bitte löschen Sie diesen nicht.";
[spellChecker checkSpellingOfString:spellCheckText startingAt:0];
NSLog(@"%@", [spellChecker language]);
```

The result is 'en' but should be 'de'.

Comment: My German is not very good, but shouldn't it be "einen deutscher Text"? Excuse me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: +1 great question! with the amount of time I spend working with the frameworks, I'm surprised I've never heard of language detection like this before.

Comment: @WTP: Nope, it's "ein". You'd say "Ich lese *einen* deutschen Text" though. ;) German is a nasty bitch. Full of entropy. ;) #native

Comment: This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890747/how-to-detect-text-string-language-in-ios/47890753#47890753) could be help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thats the result:

```
- (NSString *)languageForString:(NSString *) text{

     if (text.length < 100) {
         return (NSString *) CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage((CFStringRef)text, CFRangeMake(0, text.length));
     } else {
         return (NSString *)CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage((CFStringRef)text, CFRangeMake(0, 100));
     }
}
```

Comment: return (NSString *)CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage((CFStringRef)text, CFRangeMake(0, MIN(text.length, 100)));   should be more clear and less prone to bug introduction if you later modify the call to CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage

Comment: For a short word like "hello", it will return "it". Italian ?

Comment: Well, its work fine bit larger sentences, But "ich bin Umair" out but was "nl" instead of "de"

Answer (score 44):

There is API in cocoa available to check the language of a string, and it is always best to use Foundation over CoreFoundation whenever possible.

```
NSArray *tagschemes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage, nil];
NSLinguisticTagger *tagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes:tagschemes options:0];
[tagger setString:@"Das ist ein bisschen deutscher Text. Bitte löschen Sie diesen nicht."];
NSString *language = [tagger tagAtIndex:0 scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage tokenRange:NULL sentenceRange:NULL];
```

Alternatively, if you happen to have mixed language text, you can use the enumerateLinguisticTagsInRange API to get the language of each word in the text.

Comment: This works great! You can even create `NSOrthography` by simply calling `[tagger orthographyAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:nil]`. Definitely the best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `-requestCheckingOfString:…` instead. `NSTextCheckingTypeOrthography` attempts to identify the language used in the string, and the completion handler receives an `NSOrthography` parameter that can be used to get information about the orthography in the string, including its dominant language.

The following example outputs `dominant language = de`:

```
NSSpellChecker *spellChecker = [NSSpellChecker sharedSpellChecker];
[spellChecker setAutomaticallyIdentifiesLanguages:YES];
NSString *spellCheckText = @"Guten Herr Mustermann. Dies ist ein deutscher Text. Bitte löschen Sie diesen nicht.";

[spellChecker requestCheckingOfString:spellCheckText
    range:(NSRange){0, [spellCheckText length]}
    types:NSTextCheckingTypeOrthography
    options:nil
    inSpellDocumentWithTag:0
    completionHandler:^(NSInteger sequenceNumber, NSArray *results, NSOrthography *orthography, NSInteger wordCount) {
        NSLog(@"dominant language = %@", orthography.dominantLanguage);
}];
```

Comment: This code works perfectly. Can anybody know the swift 2.1 equivalent

Answer (score 6):

A swift String extension for Jennifer's answer:

```
extension String {
    func language() -> String? {
        let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: [NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage], options: 0)
        tagger.string = self
        return tagger.tagAtIndex(0, scheme: NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage, tokenRange: nil, sentenceRange: nil)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let language = "What language is this?".language()
```

Comment: let language = "%".language() // ---> this is a crash!

Comment: Didn't know this was supported in iOS - awesome

Comment: #Tim FriedLand than don't forcefully wrappe it. just leave it optional. it will show nil value when don't understand the language.

Answer (score 4):

With Swift 5, you can choose one of the following approaches in order to detect the language of a given string.

---

### #1. Using `NSLinguisticTagger`'s `dominantLanguage` property

Since iOS 11, `NSLinguisticTagger` has a property called [`dominantLanguage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger/2875112-dominantlanguage). `dominantLanguage` has the following declaration:

```
var dominantLanguage: String? { get }
```

> Returns the dominant language of the string set for the linguistic tagger.

The Playground sample code below show how to use `dominantLanguage` in order to know the dominant language of a string:

```
import Foundation

let text = "あなたはそれを行うべきではありません。"
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: [.language], options: 0)
tagger.string = text
let language = tagger.dominantLanguage
print(language) // Optional("ja")
```

---

### #2. Using `NSLinguisticTagger`'s `dominantLanguage(for:)` method

As an alternative, `NSLinguisticTagger` has a convenience method called [`dominantLanguage(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger/2875117-dominantlanguage) for creating a new linguistic tagger, setting its [`string`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger/1407750-string) property and getting the `dominantLanguage` property. `dominantLanguage(for:)` has the following declaration:

```
class func dominantLanguage(for string: String) -> String?
```

> Returns the dominant language for the specified string.

Usage:

```
import Foundation

let text = "Die Kleinen haben friedlich zusammen gespielt."
let language = NSLinguisticTagger.dominantLanguage(for: text)
print(language) // Optional("de")
```

---

### #3. Using `NLLanguageRecognizer`'s `dominantLanguage` property

Since iOS 12, `NLLanguageRecognizer` has a property called [`dominantLanguage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nllanguagerecognizer/2976556-dominantlanguage). `dominantLanguage` has the following declaration:

```
var dominantLanguage: NLLanguage? { get }
```

> The most likely language for the processed text.

Here’s how to use `dominantLanguage` to guess the dominant language of natural language text:

```
import NaturalLanguage

let string = "J'ai deux amours. Mon pays et Paris."
let recognizer = NLLanguageRecognizer()
recognizer.processString(string)
let language = recognizer.dominantLanguage
print(language?.rawValue) // Optional("fr")
```

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 11 you can use the `dominantLanguage(for:)`/`dominantLanguageForString:` class method of `NSLinguisticTagger`.

Swift:

```
extension String {
    var language: String? {
        return NSLinguisticTagger.dominantLanguage(for: self)
    }
}

print("Good morning".language)
print("Buenos días".language)
```

Objective-C:

```
@interface NSString (Tagger)

@property (nonatomic, readonly, nullable) NSString *language;
@end

@implementation NSString (Tagger)

- (NSString *)language {
    return [NSLinguisticTagger dominantLanguageForString:self];
}

@end

NSLog(@"%@", @"Good morning".language);
NSLog(@"%@", @"Buenos días".language);
```

Output (for both):

> en
>   es