# How to detect the language of NSString

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nlp

Is there away to detect the language text in NSString. I need to know is which language the text is so that I display it differently.

Comment: I found the answer here: thank you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325073/detect-language-of-nsstring?rq=1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't of course.

Read about [app internationalization guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/).

Comment: You actually can. Check out the link the OP posted. Also, what does this have to do with internationalization?

Comment: There was no link when I answered. You may *guess* the language of a sentence in an heuristic way [like google translate does], but nevertheless.

Comment: You can do it. http://nshipster.com/nslinguistictagger/