# A lighter way of discovering text writing direction

Tags: ios, text, arabic

I want to determine the writing direction of a string so that I can render Right-to-Left languages such as Arabic correctly in a CALayer.

so I have this method

```
+(UITextAlignment)alignmentForString:(NSString *)astring
{
    UITextView *text = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    text.text = astring;

    if ([text baseWritingDirectionForPosition:[text beginningOfDocument] inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionForward] == UITextWritingDirectionRightToLeft) {
        return UITextAlignmentRight;
    }

    return UITextAlignmentLeft;

}
```

Works fine but feels a little heavy just for the purpose of discovering which way to align my text especially as its been called in drawInContext (although relatively infrequently).

Is there a lighter way of determining the writing direction for a given string or should I just stick with this under the basis of premature optimisation. And its got to be iOS 5 friendly.

Answer (score 15):

The code in the question although functional is brutally expensive. Run it through a profiler and you will find that it spends close to 80% of the time in `UITextView.setText` when used in the drawInContext method for a layer.

Most of the answer is here in [Detect Language of NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325073/detect-language-of-nsstring)

a better form is thus...

```
+(UITextAlignment)alignmentForString:(NSString *)astring
{

    if (astring.length) {

        NSArray *rightLeftLanguages = @[@"ar",@"he"];

        NSString *lang = CFBridgingRelease(CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage((CFStringRef)astring,CFRangeMake(0,[astring length])));

        if ([rightLeftLanguages containsObject:lang]) {

            return UITextAlignmentRight;

        }
    }

    return UITextAlignmentLeft;

}
```

As Arabic and Hebrew are the only Right-to-Left languages detectable by `CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage` and should also cover Persian, Urdu and Yiddish though I havent tested that.

see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left

Comment: I'm using this to determine whether the detected language is RTL: `NSLocaleLanguageDirection direction = [NSLocale characterDirectionForLanguage:language];
 return (direction == NSLocaleLanguageDirectionRightToLeft) ? NSTextAlignmentRight : NSTextAlignmentLeft;`

Comment: @Warren Burton Thanks for your smart solution, this is really a good solution regardless of what your language setting is.

Answer (score 4):

### Swift

For me the `.natural` `textAlignment` of `UITextView` did not work unless I edited the text and line from start.

Based on [the great answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16309559/933770) and [the comment below it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289095/a-lighter-way-of-discovering-text-writing-direction#comment37407009_16309559).

```
let text = "..."
let lang = CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage(text as CFString, CFRange(location: 0, length: text.characters.count))

if let lang = lang {
    let direction = NSLocale.characterDirection(forLanguage: lang as String)

    if direction == .rightToLeft {
        textView.textAlignment = .right
    }
    else {
        textView.textAlignment = .left
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since UITextAlignment is deprecated, here's an NSString category with NSWritingDirection:

```
- (NSWritingDirection)alignment{
    if (self.length) {
        NSArray *rightLeftLanguages = @[@"ar",@"he"];
        NSString *lang = CFBridgingRelease(CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage((CFStringRef)self,CFRangeMake(0,self.length)));
        if ([rightLeftLanguages containsObject:lang]) {
            return NSWritingDirectionRightToLeft;
        }
    }
    return NSWritingDirectionLeftToRight;
```

}