# Make UILabel text Right Aligned if the text is in Arabic

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, alignment, uilabel

I have implemented **Language Localization** in my iOS App. So, now user can set the Arabic Language in my iPad Application.

I am getting the localized string response from the server and now I want to set this localized string to my `UILabel` in **Right To Left** format with **Right Alignment**.

**Update :**

My server response is already in RTL format. Now, I just wanted to set the text alignment to right when I have Arabic text in my `UILabel`.

Right now I have to write code to set the alignment of `UILabel` based on the language.

So, I just want to know if there is any *property* available for `UILabel` by setting which I can make the text of `UILabel` Right Aligned in case of Arabic Language.

Comment: please apply arabic font . maybe it will solve your issue.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744447/autolayout-rtl-uilabel-text-alignment

Comment: If you set the `attributedText` property for the label, you can apply a mutable paragraph style with the *RTL* `baseWritingDirection` set. But, the label should apply the correct writing direction to the text. If you're using constraints, make sure you have your Leading and Trailing constraints set up correctly.

Comment: **I want all my labels to be**, You mean in whole project ?

Comment: check the language like in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325073/detect-language-of-nsstring?lq=1#13783833 and if it is Arabic change the label's alignment.

Answer (score 6):

For Swift3
//MARK: UILabel extension

```
extension UILabel {
func decideTextDirection () {
    let tagScheme = [NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage]
    let tagger    = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: tagScheme, options: 0)
    tagger.string = self.text
    let lang      = tagger.tag(at: 0, scheme: NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage,
                                      tokenRange: nil, sentenceRange: nil)

    if lang?.range(of:"ar") != nil {
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
    } else {
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    }
}
```

to use this add following with your label :

```
detailLabel.text = details[0]

detailLabel.decideTextDirection()
```

Answer (score 4):

have you try this.

```
 [[self label] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentNatural];
```

[AutoLayout + RTL + UILabel text alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744447/autolayout-rtl-uilabel-text-alignment?lq=1)

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: No, this will not do what the question is asking for. Natural alignment right- or left-aligns text based on the language the application is running in, *not* based on the script of the text in the label.
The question specifically asks about an app which has an internal language switcher, so this will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Display the text normally as you do in english if you are getting arabic text from server no need to align it. Just right align the text.

Comment: That's what I am doing. I just wanted to know if there is any property available for `UILabel` which can set the Alignment of `UILabel` to right if it gets the Arabic Text. Right now I have to write a code to set the alignment based on the language. I just want to know if there is any simpler way using which `UILabel` can set its alignment.

Comment: @Tushar : did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Make your text label the entire width of the view. Then the text will right align from the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting an example using the NaturalLanguage library (NSLinguisticTagger is deprecated). This builds on @jaspreetkour's answer, and also works with attributed text.

```swift
extension UILabel {

    func decideTextDirection () {
        let recognizer = NLLanguageRecognizer()
        var txt = self.text ?? ""
        if txt.isEmpty {
            // check attributed text
            txt = self.attributedText?.string ?? ""
        }
        if !txt.isEmpty {
            recognizer.processString(txt)
            if let language = recognizer.dominantLanguage {
                switch language {
                case .arabic:
                    self.textAlignment = .right
                default:
                    self.textAlignment = .left
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```