# placeholder is not taking NSTextAlignmentNatural

Tags: ios, objective-c, placeholder, direction

I have an app where I have `UITextField`.

My app is English - Arabic app.

Now what I have is as below.

```
addPostVideoURL.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
addPostVideoURL.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural; <-- Setting alignment
addPostVideoURL.textColor = pGray_343434;
addPostVideoURL.placeholder = localize(@"videoURL");
[addPostVideoURL setValue:pGray_343434 forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
addPostVideoURL.font = [self adjustDefaultFont:40];
addPostVideoURL.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

If you see, I have set the Alignment text as `NSTextAlignmentNatural`. I did this because if keyboard is arabic (& my app is english or arabic), I want textfield to  start from right side.

*With this when I changed the keyboard to English, text field start from LTR & if I change keyboard to arabic, textfield start from RTL.* ***However, the placeholder that I have is always at the left.***

***Any way how can I make placeholder alignment based on the app language?***

Comment: see this link bro may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744447/autolayout-rtl-uilabel-text-alignment

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Check my answer for how I went ahead for placeholder ;)

Comment: its works or not bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tackle this issue, below is what I did...

1. In .pch I add below

   `#define myDirection001 ([localize(@"myLang") isEqualToString:@"en"]) ? NSTextAlignmentLeft : NSTextAlignmentRight`
2. Then have code like below.

   ```
   addPostVideoURL.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   addPostVideoURL.textAlignment = myDirection001;
   addPostVideoURL.textColor = pGray_343434;
   addPostVideoURL.placeholder = localize(@"videoURL");
   [addPostVideoURL setValue:pGray_343434 forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
   addPostVideoURL.font = [self adjustDefaultFont:40];
   addPostVideoURL.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
   ```

***Make sure that delegate is set as we are going to call delegates now.***

3. Call delegate methods.

   ```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;    
       return YES;
   }

   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
       textField.textAlignment = (textField.text.length==0) ? myDirection001 : NSTextAlignmentNatural;
       return YES;
   }
   ```