# IOS 9 Arabic Alignment issue

Tags: iphone, swift, swift2, ios9

I'm working in one of the application which supports both english and arabic languages. When i switch to arabic language the IOS9 automatically manages the flow from right to left. But i have issues with some UITextFields and UITextViews. When i start typing the text in some of the textfields are aligned properly and the text in other textfield are aligned from left to right which is not proper in arabic language. i am setting the textAlignment property to NSTextAlignmentNatural. it works fine for default KeyboardType UITextFields but facing same issue when i use email keyboardType. and facing the same issues with UITextViews. So any one can help me out in this. how to align text in UITextField according text within it?  Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoLayout + RTL + UILabel text alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744447/autolayout-rtl-uilabel-text-alignment)

Comment: Thanx @Mobrockers  i have already gone through it but it but it doest work.