# Ios table view language change in each row

Tags: ios, alignment, tableview, arabic

i am designing an app that show english and arabic. Each row, it is showing different langauage.

so when i scroll, the text alignment is changing. sometime english text is aligned right and arabic text aligned left.

i need to show engligh text alignment is left and arabic text alignment is right.

it works only after i go to next view and comeback.

Comment: do you have anything through which you can detect type of language ?

Comment: is this TableViewController's subcass ?

Comment: you can use langauage iso code to detect type of language. And on that base you can change alignment.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744447/autolayout-rtl-uilabel-text-alignment?lq=1, may it's help you

Comment: Can you show us some code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening because of 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier'
Try setting text alignment based on language each time cell is reused.

Answer (score 0):

Try this when pop back to controller  :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [tblView beginUpdates];
    [tblView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tblView indexPathsForVisibleRows]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [tblView endUpdates];

}
```

Comment: textalignment is not working correctly when initalizing tableview itself.

only showing correct text alignment, after i load tableview and go to detailview then comeback