# Right to left Tableview cell in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, localization

any one please suggest me to implement RTL support tableview custom cell.
in my cell I have logo image in left side , text at middle and one more image and count in right side of the custom cell.

I have tried with Alignment right for the text its working fine but how to implement for the two controls of the ending positions.
for clear, i need to implement mirror view of the tableview cell.
I'm working Universal app with Any-Any Layout constraints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744447/autolayout-rtl-uilabel-text-alignment?lq=1 see this

Comment: i need to implement for custom tableview cell.