# How to check if NSString language matches NSLocaleLanguageCode

Tags: objective-c, string, xcode, compare, matching

I'm trying to perform a simple task in XCode of checking whether a certain NSString language matches the user's preferred language.

For example, let's say I have a string such as the following:

```
NSString *englishString = @"Good morning!";
NSString *frenchString = @"Bonjour!";
```

I know I can get the user device's preferred language using the **NSLocaleLanguageCode** value, and based on a previous Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325073/detect-language-of-nsstring), I can get the language of the NSString. However, when I compare the two values, the keys don't seem to match. Is there a better way to go about implementing this? Thanks!

The documentation for NSLocaleLanguageCode can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalelanguagecode) and the description for NSLinguisticTagger can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger?changes=_8&language=objc). NSLocaleLanguageCode returns an NSString while the tagger, and in particular, the "tagAtIndex" method returns an NSLinguisticTag key.

Comment: Update your question with example results. What do you get from `NSLocalLanguageCode` and what do you get using `NSLinguisticTagger`?

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the suggestion, added links above to the question!

Comment: FYI - I just added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51604151/1226963) to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325073/detect-language-of-nsstring) that makes it much simpler to get the language of a string if you are using iOS 11+/macOS 10.13+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a string for both. In Objective-C, `NSLinguisticTag` is a synonym for `NSString *`. Simply compare the `NSLinguisticTag` (really just an `NSString`) to the `NSString` you obtained from the locale's language code.

But a simpler solution is to use the `dominantLanguageForString:` class method of `NSLinguisticTagger` to easily get the language of a string as an `NSString`. This is much simpler than using one of the `tag...` instance methods of `NSLinguisticTagger` but it does require iOS 11+/macOS 10.13+.

```
NSLinguisticTag languageTag = ... // tag from NSLinguisticTagger

NSString *languageCode = ... // language from NSLocale

if ([languageCode isEqualToString:languageTag]) {
}
```